# Higher order component in router needs to pass router parameters

Tags: reactjs, react-router, parameter-passing, higher-order-components

I have created the following higher order componentimport React, { useEffect } from 'react'

```
export const withCall = (WrappedComponent, calllName) => {

    const HOC = () => {
        useEffect(() =>{report(calllName)}, [])
        return <WrappedComponent />
    }

    return HOC
}
```

and this route:

```
<Route exact path={pagePath/:someId} component={withCall(ContainerComponent, 'any_call_name')} />
```

In the ContainerComponent I am trying to access `this.props.match.params`... 
As long as I am not using the HoC in between (    `<Route exact path={pagePath/:someId} component={ContainerComponent} />`) I have these properties, but when I use it I can't access them anymore. 
How can I pass them down to it while keeping the higher order component generic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
const HOC = (props) => {
    useEffect(() =>{report(calllName)}, [])
    return <WrappedComponent {...props} />
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please include explanations of why this answers the question.